# Get status of all running Azure Webjob

Tags: azure, web-applications, azure-webjobs

I have deployed the continuous webjob.

I need to setup a page in my application, which list all the running Azure webjob with the current status.

Is there any API available to achieve the same?

Need to create a custom dashboard in my web application, where it shows running webjob with its status like running/stopped/success/error

Thanks!

Comment: Please see if this helps (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40400457/how-to-list-all-running-webjobs-within-an-azure-subscription-using-powershell)

Comment: I need to develop the list of web job with the current status (Running/stop/ error) in my web application.