# How to list the web jobs in azure app service using powershell?

Tags: azure, powershell, yaml, azure-powershell

I am trying to build a pipeline using YAML to deploy web jobs in azure app service. How to list the existing web jobs? I tried to use AzurePowerShell@5 task with following script:

```
Get-AzResource -ResourceGroupName "RESGRPDEV01" | ft
```

But it does not show the web job name. Could you please help?
Also, I need to create a new web job if it does not exists.

Comment: Take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40410140)? I think it may help you.

Answer (score 0):

Earlier there was a specific command to achieve the same,  but now you can't use Get-**[**AzureWebsiteJob**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/servicemanagement/azure.service/get-azurewebsitejob?view=azuresmps-4.0.0)** to get web jobs.

Instead you could try the below,

```
Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -ResourceName $AppService -ResourceType microsoft.web/sites/<Webjob-type> -ApiVersion $Apiversion
```

[image]

You will need to use the ResourceId to get the names.

Answer (score 0):

Azure CLI might help too.

```
az webapp webjob triggered list --name MyWebApp --resource-group MyResourceGroup
```

Additionally, you can query the above result and get the desired information you are looking for

```
az webapp webjob triggered list --name MyWebApp --resource-group MyResourceGroup  --query "[].{Name:name, Schedule:settings.schedule}"
```